# Jasmine spy expects to be called with "Object(...)"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, jasmine

I am completing a migration from Jasmine 1.3 to 2.0. So far I have refactored most of the code to comply with 2.0's newer syntax. However, a certain kind of tests are still failing.

In short, my test looks like this:

```
var obj = new CustomCriteria();

spyOn(my, "function");
my.function(obj);
expect(my.function).toHaveBeenCalledWith({ big: "fat object" });
```

my `CustomCriteria` class:

```
var CustomCriteria = function() {
    this.big = "fat object";
};
```

The test fails with the following:

```
Expected spy function to have been called with [ Object({ big: "fat object" }) ] but actual calls were [ ({ big: "fat object" }) ].
```

Note how the expectation has an "`Object`" wrapping around it, but the second does not. This test did not fail in < 2.0 of Jasmine, but is now failing after I update Jasmine. How can I fix this?

**Update:** I tinkered around with creating a new object via `new`ing a `function` vs. object literal syntax, and it appears that the `__proto__`s are different. Perhaps this affects Jasmine's equality comparison?

Comment: can you create a new CustomCritieria and pass that?

Comment: Seeing as you have all the necessary resources in your test scope, you might as well check for `.toHaveBeenCalledWith(obj)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Prior to version 2, objects are equal if they have the same properties and values (see [v1.3.1 code](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/blob/v1.3.1/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js#L902))

From version 2 onward, object constructors are also compared (see [v2.0 code](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/blob/v2.0.0/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js#L1883)).

In your case: `CustomCriteria` and `{}` do not have the same constructor.

**P.S.:** The exception message also changed to contain the constructor name in it.

Answer (score 1):

```
var x = {a:1}; var y ={a:1};
```

x and y will fail comparison in jasmine ( which I believe uses ===) because x and y are just references to object literals.

`expect(my.function).toHaveBeenCalledWith(obj)` wouldn't fail though since the object references would match. You could check the args of the call using my.function.calls to check equality of certain fields if you don't have the exact object reference to compare.